# Using the hickory library, is it possible to use selectors in combination with zippers?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure, and hickory, and the idea of zippers.

What I want to do is, I want to use selectors to go to one location in an HTML document. And then, I want to be able to navigate from that location, up to a parent element, and then get 2nd sibling from that point.

Is this possible to do with hickory? From what I understand, it seems as though I only have the option of using selectors, or navigating the HTML in a zipper structure, but I can't figure out how to do both, or if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    (:require
        [hickory.select :as s]
        [hickory.convert :as convert]
        [clojure.zip :as z]
...

    (let [html (convert/hiccup-to-hickory (list [:div
                                                 [:div {:class "didya"} "nevertheless"]]
                                                [:div "possible"]
                                                [:div "geometric"]))]

        (-> (s/select-locs (s/class "didya") html)
            (first)
            (z/up)
            (z/right)
            (z/right)
            (z/node)))
```

Comment: Awesome, it seems `select-locs` was the magical incantation I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The forest library can do this easily.  There is

- a [video from the last Clojure Conj](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM)
- [many examples also](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.cljc)

docs are ongoing.